# Add New Task Button On Email Message record

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, tasks, emailmessage, lightning-record-page

I need to add new task button on Email Message Record. but after I put the *New Task* on the page layout it still not appear.
what I already done is:

- Put Standard *New Task* button in Email Message Layout  -> not work
- Create new button on Email Message Object called *Create Task* and put it on page layout. -> it also doesn't work

the goal is just to put new task button on Email Message Record Page, like this following image
[image]

hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, You cannot display standard New Task button on Email message record Page even if you include on Email Message layout.

Workaround would be using custom button and below are steps.

- Create custom button, select 'Content Source' as URL and add include
  `/lightning/o/Task/new` on button.
- Include newly created button on Email Message layout under *'Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions'* and save.
- Now you should be able to see custom 'New Task' button on Email Message record page.

[image]

Comment: Its tottally work ... Thank you so much @Vinay